# Manusear valores de um data.frame

Tags: r

No link https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlYjgC4yFDHArHtSiuUbju12gZHO é possível encontrar um dataset em csv sobre irradiação solar no Brasil. A coluna `the_geom_4326` representa as longitudes e latitudes de um polígono, que representa um grid de irradiação solar. Ou seja, dentro desse grid, ocorrem os valores de irradiação solar dispostos nas demais colunas. Eu gostaria de extrair esses valores e colocar em colunas separadas, formando o total de 8 novas colunas, com os nomes

- Grid1_Long
- Grid1_Lat
- Grid2_Long
- Grid2_Lat
- Grid3_Long
- Grid3_Lat
- Grid4_Long
- Grid4_Lat

Alguma dica de como manusear esses valores? O problema é que nem sempre esses valores tem um padrão de números de carácteres.

Comment: Não consigo acessar este link, pois minha rede é bloqueada. Consegue colcoar algumas linhas do banco de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui resolver este problema no R. Entretanto, ele pode ser resolvido facilmente no terminal do Linux ou do Mac, utilizando ferramentas que já vem instaladas por padrão:

```
cat swera_ghi_inpe_hi_res.csv | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}; {print $3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7}' | 
sed s/"\"POLYGON (("//g | sed s/"))\""//g | sed s/"  "/" "/g | tail -n +2 > 
LongLat.dat
```

Os comandos que utilizei foram:

- `cat` para ler o conteúdo do arquivo csv na tela do computador
- `awk` para imprimir apenas o conteúdo das colunas dos polígonos
- vários `sed` para remover conteúdos indesejados, como as strings `"POLYGON ((`, `))\"` e dois espaços em sequência
- `tail` para não considerar o cabeçalho do arquivo original
- `>` para salvar o resultado no arquivo LongLat.dat

Agora basta ler o arquivo LongLat.dat dentro do R e combinar com os dados anteriores:

```
dados <- read.csv(file="swera_ghi_inpe_hi_res.csv")

LongLat <- read.table(file="LongLat.dat", sep=" ", header=FALSE)
names(LongLat) <- c("Grid1_Long", "Grid1_Lat", "Grid2_Long", "Grid2_Lat", 
"Grid3_Long", "Grid3_Lat", "Grid4_Long", "Grid4_Lat", "Grid5_Long", "Grid5_Lat")

dados <- cbind(dados, LongLat)
```

Perceba que acabei encontrando polígonos de 5 lados, e não de 4 como na pergunta original. Tem que ver o motivo disso aí.

Comment: Infelizmente não possuo nem Linux nem Mac. A última informação do polígono é igual a primeira, pois polígonos em GIS são definidos como sendo o último ponto igual ao primeiro para "fechar" o polígono.

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma solução apenas em R.

Não é tão curta quanto a que usa as ferramentas do terminal, mas funciona. Fiz os passos separados também para ficar mais claro.

```
# Lendo os dados
dat <- read.csv("swera_ghi_inpe_hi_res.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Removendo da coluna tudo que não é informação útil: texto e parêntesis
dat$the_geom_4326 <- gsub("[A-Z]|(\\s\\(\\()|(\\)\\))", "", dat$the_geom_4326)

#Separando os valores pela ocorrência de vírgula e espaço
poly <- strsplit(x = dat$the_geom_4326, ",?\\s")

#Transformando texto em números
poly <- lapply(poly, as.numeric)

#Transformando a lista em matriz depois em data.frame
mat <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, poly))

#Colocando os nomes das colunas
colnames(mat) <- paste0(paste0("Grid", rep(1:5, each = 2)), c("_Long", "_Lat"))

#Juntando com os dados iniciais.
dat2 <- cbind(dat, mat)
```

Apenas a título de curiosidade, uma forma em *pipe* de fazer a mesma coisa seria a seguinte:

```
library(magrittr)
dat <- read.csv("swera_ghi_inpe_hi_res.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

dat2 <- dat %>%
  .$the_geom_4326 %>%
  gsub("[A-Z]|(\\s\\(\\()|(\\)\\))", "", .) %>%
  strsplit(",?\\s") %>% 
  lapply(as.numeric) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>%
  set_colnames(paste0(paste0("Grid", rep(1:5, each = 2)), c("_Long", "_Lat"))) %>%
  cbind(dat, .)
```